# Visual Studio 2012 Microsoft Ergonomic 4000 keyboard back/forward buttons not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2012

I have the back/forward buttons configured with the Microsoft keyboard software to go to previous / next songs in my music app.

If Visual Studio is the active window then the buttons don't do anything! Play/pause continues to work.

I have Visual Studio 2012 and the latest version of the keyboard software.

I went into VS keyboard mappings but can't see anything bound to the back/forward buttons.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case this was due to Visual Studio running as administrator. If this is the case for you too try to run iTunes (or whatever music app you are running) as administrator (or switch visual studio back to non-administrator mode), that fixed it for me.

Comment: I use the Zune music player. I tried running that in admin and then I couldn't use the keyboard buttons in that app either. I took Visual Studio (2013 now) out of admin mode and the keyboard buttons work now! I need to be able to run VS in admin mode though for Azure, at least I know the reason!

Comment: Yeah the current situation kinda sucks. But from what I found is not only related to VS. Is any app in administrator mode that locks those keys:

Quote: "Also, in Windows 7 or Windows Vista, if you start a program using the Run as administrator command, you may be unable to use some IntelliType Pro software features." from http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-ca/help/support/troubleshooting/keyboard/common-issues